Could compressed air be used in a 'whipper'
I'm considering a compressed gas whipper like this or this.
They're not cheap to buy, and once they're purchased they require nitrogen, nitrous oxide or carbon dioxide cylinders to work.
This has got me thinking - why not just use compressed air? Traditional, manual whisking with fork or whisk will incorporate a lot of air (which is 80% nitrogen) into whatever is being whisked. Is there anything special about using nitrogen or nitrous oxide, or would compressed-air work much the same?

You can also make whipped cream in a regular blender which saves you from having to manually do it and from buying gas cartridges.

1st...
How do these work?
They use a Venturi nozzle with an infuser to pull the cream into the air nozzle and the high speed air mixes with the cream creating a whipped effect. This effect can be achieved by hand.
It works in a similar manner to a soap sprayer to your car.
Can I use compressed air instead of CO2 or nitrous oxide?
It would probably whip the cream just fine, but… I wouldn't recommend using any old air compressor. This is something that you eat. You will ingest everything that was inside of the air that gets whipped into the cream.
This will potentially affect the flavor of your whipped cream, and definitely add in contaminates, which may or may not be unsafe for human consumption.
That being said, its is possible to buy food grade air compressors for the low low price of a lot of money. They appear to be around 10x the cost of a regular air compressor. Which would allow you to compress your own air at home and potentially recharge the canisters (assuming they are not single use, and assuming that you can find an adapter). Is it cost effective? I don't know, depends on how often you make whipped cream using this vs. the cost of buying/maintaining a food safe air compressor. For the average person, I would estimate that this is not cost effective. But your mileage may vary.
On a side note, if you happen to own a scuba diving air compressor, it would probably be safe to use that (with a regulator). But those are also out of reach of the common consumer.

If you are suggesting filling an Isi (or that style) whipper with compressed air, it is not a good idea.  First, it would be a safety issue.  There are pressure restrictions on these devices, that would be difficult to monitor.  Second, nitrous oxide and CO2 are used because they have particular solubility characteristics in the ingredients typically placed in a whipper.  Third, you risk off flavors and contaminants from compressed air, since this isn't from a food grade source. Stick with what they are designed to use, that way you don't harm yourself or someone you are cooking for.

Typical piston-based air compressors have a lubricator oil aerosol in the compressed air they produce.

I think that your third point is the most important. As 1) pressure regulators exist, and work really, really well. 2) You can hand whip everything that a compressed air compressor whips. From my experience at least. So I don't think it has anything to do with solubility.

Re the contaminants, you could use a diving air compressor instead. Those are guaranteed not to add contaminants to the air, because you're going to be filling your lungs with it. The OP is balking at a hundred quid on the "correct" version though, so I suspect they wouldn't like the price tag on a dive tank compressor!

Solubility has to do with why nitrous oxide is used in cans. It dissolves in fat, so can is at much lower pressure, allowing to use thinner walls.  Carbon dioxide has a similar property in that it liquefies when under high pressure, which allows to store more of it in same volume than if it was just compressed, like air.

@Graham no, they are guaranteed not to add UNSAFE contaminants; they may add safe-but-not-very-tasty things: I don't see why they may not (unintentionally) add a metallic or lemony flavour as long as harmless (including, not an allergen)?

You generally want to avoid air--or more specifically, oxygen--even if it were totally clean because it will oxidize food and give whipped cream rancid flavors. NO2 is also slightly bacteriostatic, which helps the product last longer.
